# Sierra 12.6 dark theme, system icons stay black

Tags: icon, menu-bar

When I enable the dark dock + menubar option, system icons on the upper right corner remain black instead of becoming white. To be clear, the menus on the left hand side switch correctly, as do my app icons (Skype, BTT, etc), and Spotlight:

[image: Icons staying dark]

I normally use flux.io to switch to the dark theme at sunset, but this happens even when disabling flux and switching manually.

I really don't know where to look to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: After a few weeks it's back to normal.